# Generation of Base64 string from JPG/PNG/... image returns plain white image after canvas resize operation

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, base64

## Context

I'm trying to generate a Base64 string of a JPG/PNG/... image after resizing it. For some reason, the resulting Base64 string is that of a plain white image.

## Assumption

My assumption of what is causing this, is the following: `<canvas width="X" height="Y"></canvas>` does not seem to contain innerHTML, where I would expect it to contain `<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/6068b5_b0d5df4c3d094694bb5d348eac41128d~mv2.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous">` However, I cannot figure out why `ctx.drawImage()` does not handle this.

## Related issues

Several other people have brought up this issue, but unfortunately, the proposed solutions didn't seem to resolve my issue. See:

1. [Rendering a base64 image, currently comes back as blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199422/rendering-a-base64-image-currently-comes-back-as-blank)
2. [How can I convert an image into Base64 string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)
3. [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

## Minimal Working Example

```js
async function init(){
    //getDataUrl
    var dataUrl = await getDataUrl("https://static.wixstatic.com/media/6068b5_5888cb03ab9643febc221f3e6788d656~mv2.jpg");
    console.log(dataUrl); //returns string, but white image?
    //Create new image on body tag with dataurl
    addBase64Image(dataUrl);
}

function getImageDimensions(file) {
    return new Promise (function (resolved, rejected) {
        var i = new Image()
        i.onload = function(){
            resolved({w: i.width, h: i.height})
        };
        i.src = file
    })
}

async function getDataUrl(img_url) {
    // Create canvas
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var dimensions = await getImageDimensions(img_url);
    console.log(dimensions);

    // Set width and height
    canvas.width = dimensions.w; //img_url.width
    canvas.height = dimensions.h; //img_url.height

    var res = await loadImage(ctx, img_url, dimensions.w, dimensions.h);
    console.log(res);
    res.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
    ctx.drawImage(res, dimensions.w, dimensions.h); //issue: <canvas width="2075" height="3112"></canvas> has no innerHTML e.g. <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/6068b5_b0d5df4c3d094694bb5d348eac41128d~mv2.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous">
    console.log(canvas);
    console.log(ctx);
    
    dataurl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    return dataurl;
}

function loadImage(context, path, dimx, dimy){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var img=new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            resolve.call(null, img);
        };
        img.src=path;
    });
}

function calculateAspectRatioFit(srcWidth, srcHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
    var ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight);
    return { width: srcWidth*ratio, height: srcHeight*ratio };
}

async function addBase64Image(img_dataurl){
    var dimensions = await getImageDimensions(img_dataurl);
    console.log(dimensions);
    var res = calculateAspectRatioFit(dimensions.w, dimensions.h, 512, 512);
    console.log(res);

    var image = document.createElement("img");
    var imageParent = document.querySelector('body');
    image.id = "user_upload";
    image.width = res.width;
    image.height = res.height; 
    image.src = img_dataurl;           
    imageParent.appendChild(image);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#user_upload {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2.5px solid;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to draw an image hosted on a different domain onto a canvas

a) the webserver needs to permit it and send the appropriate headers

b) you need to set the `crossOrigin` property of the image to `"anonymous"`

Obviously you already figured this out yourself, as you already have the line

```
res.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
```

in your code.

The problem is that it happens too **late**. It needs to be set before assigning an URL to the `src` property of the image.

So simply move the above line inside the `loadImage()` function, just before the call to

```
img.src=path;
```

Here's an example:

```js
async function init() {
  //getDataUrl
  var dataUrl = await getDataUrl("https://static.wixstatic.com/media/6068b5_5888cb03ab9643febc221f3e6788d656~mv2.jpg");
  console.log(dataUrl); //returns string, but white image?
  //Create new image on body tag with dataurl
  addBase64Image(dataUrl);
}

function getImageDimensions(file) {
  return new Promise(function(resolved, rejected) {
    var i = new Image()
    i.onload = function() {
      resolved({
        w: i.width,
        h: i.height
      })
    };
    i.src = file
  })
}

async function getDataUrl(img_url) {
  // Create canvas
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var dimensions = await getImageDimensions(img_url);
  console.log(dimensions);

  // Set width and height
  canvas.width = dimensions.w; //img_url.width
  canvas.height = dimensions.h; //img_url.height

  var res = await loadImage(ctx, img_url, dimensions.w, dimensions.h);
  console.log("asd ", res);

  ctx.drawImage(res, 0, 0); //issue: <canvas width="2075" height="3112"></canvas> has no innerHTML e.g. <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/6068b5_b0d5df4c3d094694bb5d348eac41128d~mv2.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous">
  console.log(canvas);
  console.log(ctx);

  dataurl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  return dataurl;
}

function loadImage(context, path, dimx, dimy) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      resolve.call(null, img);
    };
    img.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
    img.src = path;

  });
}

function calculateAspectRatioFit(srcWidth, srcHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
  var ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight);
  return {
    width: srcWidth * ratio,
    height: srcHeight * ratio
  };
}

async function addBase64Image(img_dataurl) {
  var dimensions = await getImageDimensions(img_dataurl);
  console.log(dimensions);
  var res = calculateAspectRatioFit(dimensions.w, dimensions.h, 512, 512);
  console.log(res);

  var image = document.createElement("img");
  var imageParent = document.querySelector('body');
  image.id = "user_upload";
  image.width = res.width;
  image.height = res.height;
  image.src = img_dataurl;
  imageParent.appendChild(image);
}

init();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#user_upload {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2.5px solid;
}
```